# How can Google Play publishing be so instable?

Tags: android, google-play

This is the situation: 
- We published version 2 on Google Play 24 hours ago. The previous version was called version 1.
- Today I could find version 2 on my sons Android phone (Huawei Mate 10 Pro). Version 1 was installed previously.
- At the same time I try installing it from my test phone, Huawei TIT-L01. Here I only see the old version 1 in Google Play. I have tried everything. Restarted Google Play. Uninstalled all previous version of the app, I unstalled all test versions of the app etc.

Any suggestions on why this can happen will be appreciated.

Here is a link for the app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.dsg.clubsalling

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about app distribution channels are considered to be off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: Google play will roll out updates in batches. Once the update is rolled out completely, you will receive a notification in your play console.

Answer (score -1):

- You will have changed something in your manifest meaning version 2 is not compatible with your phone, only compatible with your test phone. If you paste your old and new build.gradle people may be able to help you.
- There is also a feature called "Device Library" in the Play console which lets you look at different devices and investigate compatibility.
- Finally, whenever you do a new release the Play console tells you if the new version is compatible with more or fewer devices than the previous version. If it is not compatible with your test phone, you should have seen this number go down.